# ¿ Como añadir shortcodes a la ficha de productos junto a otros campos?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesito añadir un contador regresivo a algunos de los productos que quiero promocionar, una cuenta a tras para el dia que salen a la venta.

Encontre un Plugin con el que hacer, y con el `shortcode` que genera, puedo colocar este contador regresivo en el lugar que quiera.

Este  caso, tambien quiero añadirlo debajo del título de la ficha del producto en cuestión, y solo a ese, en la pagina de del catalogo de productos. Es como si añadiéramos una marca en este caso en forma de `shortcode`.

Ya tengo dos , uno para introducir texto y otro para añadir una imagen. Gracias a este código, puedo añadir editando cada producto, o bien un texto o la `url` de una imagen,  en el campo creado.

Yo quiero añadir un campo nuevo debajo de estos para añadir un shortcode de la cuenta regresiva al producto que lo desee.
Por más veces que probe, no lo consigo, no encuentro la forma de añadir  a las `etiquetas` de `html`  el shortcode generado con el `plugin` para la cuenta regresiva.

He probado con lo siguiente, pero no se muestra.
unicamente se muestra el texto del código:

```
/* Registramos el Metabox= */

function biogredos_custom_product_metabox()
{
  // Memberships Metabox
  add_meta_box(
    'product-custom-settings',
    __('Producto', 'textdomain'),
    'custom_product_callback',
    'product'
  );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'biogredos_custom_product_metabox');

/* Agregamos los campos*/
function custom_product_callback()
{

  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if ($screen->action !== 'add') :

    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

    $logo = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_logo', true);
    $texto = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_title', true);
    $descuento = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_contando', true);//shortcode

  else :

    $logo = '';
    $texto =  '';
    $descuento = ''; //shortcode

  endif;

  // Logo
  echo '<div class="trn-form-control">';
  echo '<div class="trn-row">';
  echo '<div class="trn-col-2"><label>Logo</label></div>';
  echo '<div class="trn-col-10">';
  echo '<input type="text" id="custom-product-logo" name="custom-product-logo" value="' . $logo . '">';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';

  // Titulo
  echo '<div class="trn-form-control">';
  echo '<div class="trn-row">';
  echo '<div class="trn-col-2"><label>Titulo</label></div>';
  echo '<div class="trn-col-10">';
  echo '<input type="text" id="custom-product-title" name="custom-product-title" value="' . $texto . '">';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';


  // Descuento -  shortcode
  echo '<div class="trn-form-control">';
  echo '<div class="trn-row">';
  echo '<div class="trn-col-2"><label>Shortcode</label></div>';
  echo '<div class="trn-col-10">';
  echo '<input type="text" id="custom-product-contando" name="custom-product-contando" value="' . $descuento . '">';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}

/* Guardamos los datos*/
function biogredos_product_save_custom($post_id)
{

  $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
  if ($post_type == 'product') :

    $logo  = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom-product-logo']);
    $titulo  = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom-product-title']);
    $contando = sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom-product-contando']);//shortcode

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_logo', $logo);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_title', $titulo);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_contando', $contando); //shortcode

  endif;
}
add_action('save_post', 'biogredos_product_save_custom');

/* Mostramos los datos */

function biogredos_show_custom_product_data()
{

  global $product;
  $post_id = $product->get_id();

  $logo = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_logo', true);
  $texto = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_title', true);
  $shortcode = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ct_product_contando', true);

  if ($logo) :
    echo '<img class="degradableimage" src="' . $logo . '">';
  endif;

  if ($texto) :
    echo '<p class="degradable">' . $texto . '</p>';
  endif;

  if ($shortcode) :
    echo '<p class="descuento">' . $shortcode . '</p>';
  endif;
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'biogredos_show_custom_product_data');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplemente cambia esta parte

```
echo '<p class="descuento">' . $shortcode . '</p>';
```

Por esto:

```
echo '<p class="descuento">' . do_shortcode( $shortcode ) . '</p>';
```

Si por alguna razón esto no funciona muy posiblemente el plugin usa la función has_shortcode() para encolar los scripts, si es asi tocara encolar los scripts de forma manual.

Puedes leer más aquí https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo.  Mañana la pregunta es apta para recompensa, gracias a esta respuesta y a la anterior, empleare los puntos que quedan de reputación para agradecértelo, gracias @JefferzonBol